# Has China approved (any) Western vaccines for travel purposes?

Tags: china, borders, vaccine

Back when they had launched their vaccine travel passport in March, China only included [its own vaccines](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/covid-vaccine-travel-visa-rules-intl-hnk/index.html) in their green list.

I see that Pfizer is [still struggling](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2021/08/30/asia-pacific/china-pfizer-approval-pending/) to obtain approval in China for clinical use, but **has China approved any Western vaccine for travel purposes**, in the meantime?

([A minority](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/eu-travel-covishield-sinopharm-sinovac-vaccines-are-most-widely-accepted-by-eu-countries-after-those-authorised-by-ema/) of EU countries have approved the Chinese vaccines for travel purposes, after the EU as a whole declined, leaving it up to individual member countries.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they have. While no western are approved for use in China, three are accepted for travel purposes.

As reported by [The Washington Post in April](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/china-vaccine-passport-visas-covid/2021/04/20/8a6422d0-a14e-11eb-8a6d-f1b55f463112_story.html):

> The Chinese Embassy in Washington said [in an online notice](https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/ce/ceus/chn/lszj/zytz/t1869583.htm) late last week that Pfizer-BioNTech, Moderna and Johnson & Johnson vaccine records can be submitted as part of an application for a coronavirus QR “health code” — China’s version of a [vaccine passport](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2021/02/18/coronavirus-passports-pandemic-travel/?itid=lk_inline_manual_3) and a requirement to enter the country.
>
> Previously, China said it would facilitate entry only for those who have received Chinese vaccines, drawing backlash in countries where they aren’t available. No foreign coronavirus vaccine has yet been approved for use within China.

Comment: China still seems to quarantine all arrivals, even vaccinated ones, and seemingly regardless of which vaccine. Although they also check vaccination status upon entry... https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/china-travel-covid-19/index.html